# How do i add SAN DISK to a virtual server using knife command?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, knife

Currently we create VS using following command

```
knife softlayer server create  
--image-id ${image_id}  
--ssh-keys ${ssh_keys}  
--hostname $node_name  
--network-interface-speed 100  
--domain $domain_name  
--cores ${cores}  
--ram ${ram}  
--datacenter ${datacenter}  
--node-name $node_name  
--vlan $public_vlan  
--private-vlan $private_vlan  
--use-private-network  
-x root  
-i $USER_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa  -VV
```

Now we want to add a 100 GB SAN to the above created VS.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add the `--san-storage` and specify `--block-storage 0:100`. SoftLayer virtual servers always reserve device 1 for a swap device, so 0 would represent the primary drive and 2-5 would represent additional drives.

Comment: I just noticed that you are using an image. In this case it is not possible to adjust the primary drive size. It will inherit the size from the system the image template was taken from. You should however be able to use the commands listed above and start at `2:100`.

Comment: i couldnot find any option --san-storage. -B, --block-storage VALUE this can be used to add SAN disks?

Comment: The `--block-storage VALUE` will work for both Local and SAN storage as far as I am aware.

Comment: I get following error if i use --blockstorage 2:100 :body          => "{\"error\":\"Invalid value provided for 'blockDevices'. Block devices may not be provided when using an image template.\",\"code\":\"SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue\"}"

Comment: I guess the use of an image template precludes adding additional SAN or LOCAL drives during the order process. You can open an issue here to see if that is something that could be added in the future: 

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues